# How to get all links (href,src,url) attributes from bs4.elements.tag in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I know this works

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(some_response.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("a")
for link in links:
   print(link["href"])
```

..but this only prints the links with the `href` attribute.

Without hard-coding `link["src"]` and `link["url"]`,
is there any other way to get ANY link attribute of a tag object? (i.e get any url even if its attribute is called "href", "src", "img", etc)

Comment: use `.attrs` to access the attributes! and then loop over keys to access values.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can loop over all `.attrs` for a given tag as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" src="/test1.html" img="/test2.html" etc="/test3.html">link</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    for attr in a.attrs:
        print(attr, a[attr])
```

This would display:

```
href http://www.stackoverflow.com
src /test1.html
img /test2.html
etc /test3.html
```

You would though need a method to determine if each result is actually a link.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible variations when it comes to tags referencing some kind of URL/hyperlink. See the HTML docs: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html and look for `%URI`

That said if you are only interested in say all tags/elements with the attributes `src` and `href`, this should work:

```
html = """
<link href="some_link">
<script src="/some/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<img src="some_image.jpg">
<a href="https://www.company.com">My Company</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for attr in ['src', 'href']:
    tags = soup.select(f"[{attr}]")
    for tag in tags:
        print(f"{attr}'s url:'{tag.attrs[attr]}' for tag:{tag}")
```

Since it will yield this:

```
src's url:'/some/script.js' for tag:<script src="/some/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
src's url:'some_image.jpg' for tag:<img src="some_image.jpg"/>
href's url:'some_link' for tag:<link href="some_link"/>
href's url:'https://www.company.com' for tag:<a href="https://www.company.com">My Company</a>
```